# Chrome: debugging local typescript files doesn't work anymore

Tags: typescript

Chrome doesn't diplay the files anymore. Works fine, when the are served and also local with FireFox. Sourcemaps exist and are valid. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Chrome Version 73.0.3683.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you clarify what you mean with "Chrome doesn't display the file anymore"?

Comment: Usually, the .ts-files are shown alongside the .js-files in the debugger of the chrome browser

Comment: Do you host your JS files on your own computer or on a remote server when seeing this issue?

Comment: As in the headline: local. Works when served remotely

Comment: We have the issue on several windows machines, but I haven't been able to find something about it in the net. Can anybody try to see if it's a common problem?

Comment: Are we the only people facing this problem? Tested on several machines...